# Share and update URL to a remote browser

Tags: web-browser, url

I'm looking for a way to share an ad-hoc series of URLs to a remote web browser (the client) in real time.

The client sees this (more or less):

1. Accept initial request from the serving browser.
2. URL loads in that tab and automatically updates to match the serving browser's URL.
3. Only URL is synced, not scrollbar or cursor.
4. Closing the tab breaks the connection.

The serving browser sees this (more or less):

1. Send request to remote browser.
2. Notify that the remote browser is successfully connected.
3. Change the current url by following links or changing the address bar.
4. Closing the tab breaks the connection.

Use cases / motivation:

1. Ad-hoc web-based presentations.
2. Semi-guided tutorials for how to navigate a website without using e.g. TeamViewer.
3. Link-sharing without using external applications like email or chat clients.
4. Playing the [Wiki Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wiki_Game).

Stipulations:

1. Exposes only a single tab, not all tabs and history.
2. No screen-sharing software; I want to transfer the URL, not full HTML pages or cookies.
3. Must not require setting up a web server.
4. URL *updates* use only a web browser and possibly addons, however:
5. The initial request may take the form of a URL sent via email or instant message, but preferably is directly browser-to-browser.
6. URL updates must not require a manual page refresh on the client.
7. URL updates must not require a manual update from the serving browser, just a match to whatever URL is in that tab's address bar.
8. Must not require receiving (client) browser to register an account.
9. Must be cross-browser for client (Firefox and Chrome at the very least).

Remarks:

1. Ideally the serving browser is not required to register an account, but I realize this could make things difficult.
2. Recent browser features like WebSockets or WebRTC are acceptable for both the client and the serving browsers.
3. One to one is required, but one-to-many would be a nice bonus.
4. Being able to see the position of the remote cursor would also be useful, but is by no means required.
5. Open source is preferred, but not critical.

[Sendtab](http://sendtab.com/) (https://vimeo.com/46774425) requires registration for the client and manual updates for the serving browser, so that's out. Also seems to be defunct right now.

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/sendtab.com

[Framote](http://framote.com/) meets most of the requirements, but requires manually changing the current link, and I haven't been able to get it to successfully update the URL.

Firefox Sync synchronizes all tabs, not a single tab.

Note: answers to the effect of "This is impossible with the constraints you describe" are acceptable, but they must identify which constraints are the problem and how they can be overcome, not just something like "this appears to violate the same-origin policy".

Comment: http://shove.wtf/ allows you to open a tab in a client's Chrome window, but it doesn't change/auto remove on closure... :/